# Discrepancy in decimal rounding results

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

Using Java:

```
$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 17.0.3
|  For an introduction type: /help intro
```

Using 'half even' rounding method, 3084.5 rounds to 3084:

```
jshell> new java.math.BigDecimal("3084.5").setScale(0, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
$13 ==> 3084
```

But 3084.51 rounds to 3085:

```
jshell> new java.math.BigDecimal("3084.51").setScale(0, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
$13 ==> 3085
```

Why is the digit `1` affecting the rounding? It's beyond the last significant digit (`5`) that should be considered during the rounding operation, right?

Comment: Why do you think there's a last significant digit that should be considered?  They get rounded as real numbers, and 3084.51 is not on the "HALF" line but above it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, thanks, I had always considered significant digits when rounding, I wasn't aware that Java rounding is done by considering the entire number.

Comment: This isn't unique to Java, or to pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Huh. Mind blown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc of `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`:

> Rounding mode to round towards the {@literal "nearest neighbor"} unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.

That means, with a scale of `0` that you set in the `.setScale()` (meaning you want 0 decimals):

- `3084.5` is equidistant from `3084` and `3085`, so it will be the even neighbor (hence `3084` that is even, not `3085` that is odd).
- `3084.51` is not equidistant, it is `0.01` closer to `3085` than `3084`, hence it will be the nearest neighbor.